# How can I install multiple apps on Ubuntu using scripting?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, desktop-apps

I would like to install a lot of apps, and I has been saving all commands to install each app, here is a sample:

```
##Global

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install indicator-multiload spotify-client sublime-text qbittorrent gimp virtualenv rar unrar postgresql pgadmin3 python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev p7zip-full

##Kaggle

pip install kaggle
chmod 600 /home/username/.kaggle/kaggle.json

##Jdownloader

wget http://installer.jdownloader.org/JD2SilentSetup_x64.sh
chmod +x JD2SilentSetup*.sh
./JD2SilentSetup*.sh

##Teamviewer

sudo wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends teamviewer_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo teamviewer --daemon start
teamviewer
```

How can I run all lines at once using scripting on bash command line?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you save all those commands to a file?  If so, you would just launch it with the command `bash /path/to/filename`

Comment: Yes, in deep the file name and extension are: ubuntu.txt , So, I must just save it as .sh? or just `bash ubuntu.txt`?

Comment: Extensions don't matter in Linux.  You can make the file executable by running `chmod +x filename` but, you would have to add a line to the beginning stating what shell it is going to launch in.  The first line of the file would have something similar to `#!/bin/bash`. 
 However, you don't have to do that if you just put `bash` in front of it then it will try to run each line individually.  So, yes, `bash ubuntu.txt` would work just fine.

Comment: Perfect! And If the instalation of a few packages takes a lot of time (5 minutes to download) I need to enter my sudo password a lot of times?

Comment: I think the timeout is 15 minutes on `sudo`.  So, yes, you might have to if it takes longer than that.  From my understanding though, each time it runs `sudo` starts the timer again, so you might only need it once.

Comment: Ooops, I guess it is 5 minutes on the timeout, but you might still be OK.